# How to create context menu for recyclerView in PreferenceFragmentCompat class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, contextmenu, androidx

In a preference fragment class , getListView returns a recyclerView. 
How can I create context menu for this list items inside recycler view ?
List items are preferences created using code hierarchy

```
public static class ProfileListScreenFragment extends 
     PreferenceFragmentCompat  {

   @Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) 
{

        setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
  savedInstance{
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  registerForContextMenu(getListView()); // get list view returns a 
                                            recycler view

 }
@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(@NonNull ContextMenu menu, @NonNull View v, 
  @Nullable ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
           .....
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you must create the menu in fragment and call it in adapter on specific operations via an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by registering context menu listener on view holder inside the preference fragment class.

```
public class TestFragmentClass extends PreferenceFragmentCompat{     

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PreferenceViewHolder holder, final 
    int position) {
                super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

                final ViewGroup itemView  = (ViewGroup) holder.itemView;
                itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh  = getListView().getChildViewHolder(v);
                        int position = vh.getAdapterPosition();
                       .....
                 }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      // override onContextItemSelected here

    }
```

Comment: I cannot override `onBindViewHolder`. It is not a method of `PreferenceFragmentCompat` but a method inside `androidx.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter`